# Unity3d Application.persistentDataPath

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, path, screenshot

In my application, I have created a screenshot with *Application.CaptureScreenshot* function and save it using *Application.persistentDataPath*.

The problem is that **I don't see these images in folder**. Under PlayerSettings I changed WriteAcceess on *External (SD card)*. 
Ideally, I need to save screenshots so that they are displayed in the Gallery. I don't need protect that data => screenshots can be removed or replaced by users.

> By logs *Persistent Data Path* is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.arda.test/files/